# Is there a way to restore software classes registry keys

Tags: registry, windows-vista, boot, regedit

I accidentally deleted registry keys under hkey_current_user>software>classes. The classes folder got completely deleted. The moment I did that system stopped functioning properly.

And, since then system doesn't boot up to login screen. A black screen with pointer appears. I tried system repair but it din't work. I could transfer files from C Drive to external Drive.

In safe mode it loads drivers list but gets "Stuck" on aswrvrt.sys where it stays for 20-30 seconds.  It then shows the "Starting Windows" screen for 20-30 seconds then all I see on the black screen is the mouse cursor.

I can see the Registry editor using cmd.exe. Is there a way I can restore previous registries or copy files externally?

Answer (score 0):

You could use system restore in safe mode if you can get into it.  Press F8 when the computer is booting.

Comment: Man, me and @darc pressed submit with the same answer 2 seconds apart.  Just putting that on here so I don't get downvoted for pople thinking I was copying an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to restore your computer/laptop to previous date to do so boot into safe pressing F8 key during system start up.

Answer (score 0):

In safe mode try uninstalling and reinstalling Avast (your antivirus).

That being said, the registry editor can import those keys and even entire nodes, but you have to have exported them prior, or export them from another system... and that may not work very well - depending on what was in those keys (licenses info, etc.)